# Import swift iOS project to another project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, import, project

Im really sucked, and didn't find any information what can help me.

So:

I have a project, named ProjectA. This is the main project. 
I would like to import to ProjectA one open source swift game, named projectB. ProjectB has workspace file, while projectA doesn't.

After that, I would like to call the projectB's Main.storyboard from projectA's storyboard trough a storyboard reference.

I tried everything, target dependencies, import, same workspace, etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this example : -

**http://tuchangwei.github.io/2013/09/16/how-to-import-one-project-to-another-one-in-xcode/**

Due to user needs, I have to import one project to another one as a sub-project. The final result should be like the following picture.

It is not easy to do this. We need some steps.

Step 1, Add “project.xcodeproj” file to project, note that don’t choose the “Copy items into…”.

Step 2, close the project, because you have opened the project in project. If you don’t, you can just see the “project.xcodeproj” file and there is no triangle front of it, you will can’t expand it.

Step 3, generate static library. Choose “project.xcodeproj”,add Target. After generating static library, add swift file framework files to it.

Step 4, generate Bundle, and change the relevant settings to iOS target.

Comment: you solution is good but its very old can you please help me sahre a video for this any link?